# How to winforms C# application having two image folder?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a situation that there are two image folders containing images. These image folder are dynamically populated with images. I have made these image folder under project directory of visual studio. Its working fine before publishing. After publishing, one image folder gives me images but for the next one I am not getting any images .

I have made all images property as `Build` in action as `Content` and copy always

Comment: Are all images dynamically generated, or do some already exist prior to execution?  Does image data already exist in these folders prior to build?

Comment: There are existing images in their respective folder and we can also add new images to image folder as our need

Comment: Try changing the **Build Action** to "None" and leave **Copy to Output Directory** to "Copy Always".

Comment: Write or copy your images folders beside your executable file and get path as var `myFirstImagePath1 = Application.StartupPath + @"\ImageFolder1\myImage1.png";` and 
                `var myFirstImagePath2 = Application.StartupPath + @"\ImageFolder2\myImage2.png";`

Comment: Regarding above comment, if you are doing programmatically then you need to create directories as ImageFolder1 and ImageFolder2 then write image files.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked a little with a folder that's dynamically populated from some old legacy framework we were using at my last company.

Be sure your file permissions are set properly on the folders that images are being dynamically populated..  Whatever process or user profile that's writing to that folder will need the proper file permissions to do so.

Also ensure your process that is populating those folders are also targeting the published site properly.